# Powershell - Parse windows events and extract xml data information

Tags: powershell, events

I required your help regarding this subject.

Context:

I am looking for a way to parse evt (or evtx) files based on id (example: 302) and extract the data available in the xml field of the event.

Event xml format is:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="MyProgr" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49154">302</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-05-31T14:55:59.040708600Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>772</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>Server.lan</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>A text relating this event</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

My goal is to get a similar output (based on sample above):

```
Event: 302 

The 2021-05-31T14:55:59 on Server.lan, MyProgr raise the following message: 
A text relating this event
```

Do you have any good idea to address my needs?

**Solution**

```
$events = Get-WinEvent  -FilterHashTable @{LogName = "Application"; id=302} -MaxEvents 50 | where {$_.Message -like '*'}
foreach($event in $events){
"-"*50                        
            write-host "Date:" $event.TimeCreated
            write-host "Source:"$event.ProviderName
            $event.Message             
"-"*50
}
```

Comment: There's a `Get-WinEvent` command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 1):

Using the example xml file.

For demo below as Here-String, but in real life you would load it from file using

```
# Best use below method to load an XML from file, because it automatically detects the file encoding
$xml= New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
$xml.Load("path\eventfile.evt")
```

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<Event
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="MyProgr" />
        <EventID Qualifiers="49154">302</EventID>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-05-31T14:55:59.040708600Z" />
        <EventRecordID>772</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>Server.lan</Computer>
        <Security />
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>A text relating this event</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
"@

# create an output template with 4 placeholders
# {0} --> The EventID
# {1} --> The TimeCreated SystemTime where everything after the dot is removed
# {2} --> The Computer name
# {3} --> The message
$out = @"
Event: {0} 

The {1} on {2}, MyProgr raise the following message: 
{3}
"@

# for output, just fill in the placeholders
$out -f $xml.Event.System.EventID.'#text', 
        ($xml.Event.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime -replace '\.\d+.*$'),
        $xml.Event.System.Computer,
        $xml.Event.EventData.Data
```

Output:

```
Event: 302 

The 2021-05-31T14:55:59 on Server.lan, MyProgr raise the following message: 
A text relating this event
```

---

For your added question, I would recommend parsing the events using Get-WinEvent:

```
$filter = "*[System[EventID=302 and Provider[@Name='MyProgr']]]"
$result = Get-WinEvent -LogName Application -FilterXPath $filter | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
    # output the properties you need
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        EventID       = $eventXml.System.EventID.'#text'
        TimeCreated   = $eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime -replace '\.\d+.*$'
        Computer      = $eventXml.System.Computer
        Data          = $eventXml.EventData.Data
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save as CSV file if you like
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'path\to\MyProgr_Events_302.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Or use this result to output formatted according to the template, same as before:

```
# create an output template with 4 placeholders
# {0} --> The EventID
# {1} --> The TimeCreated SystemTime where everything after the dot is removed
# {2} --> The Computer name
# {3} --> The message
$out = @"
Event: {0} 

The {1} on {2}, MyProgr raise the following message: 
{3}
"@

$result | ForEach-Object {
    # for output, just fill in the placeholders
    $out -f $_.EventID,
            $_.TimeCreated,
            $_.Computer,
            $_.Data
}
```

Comment: Hello Theo, 
Thanks for this sample.
I think that the xml file is the problem, xml structure seem drastically different than information I can get into Events, details and xml view.
In Events, details and xml view I have a similar information provided in my initial post, but in xml file datas are more chaotics.

It is possible to get all event with 302 ID and display data into EventData

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the event to `xml` and then read it:

```
Get-WinEvent -Path "C:\test.evtx" -Oldest | ConvertTo-Xml -as Stream -Depth 10 > "C:\test\test.xml"
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path "C:\test.xml"
```

Now you can easily read it and parse the output:

```
Write-Host "Event: $($xml.Event.System.EventID.'#text')"
Write-Host "The $(([Datetime]$xml.Event.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")) on $($xml.Event.System.Computer), $($xml.Event.System.Provider.Name) raise the following message:`n$($xml.Event.EventData.Data)"
```

Output:

```
Event: 302
The 2021-05-31T05:55:59 on Server.lan, MyProgr raise the following message: 
A text relating this event
```

Comment: Hello Shayky, 
Thanks for your answer
When i said it's xml format, it's a part on evt. When you open an event, you can click on detail then view xml format. In my case I do not have a an xml file

Comment: Hello Shayky, 
Thanks for your fast answer. 
I've just tested the solution and got an error regarding time convertion, see below:
Unable to convert the value Null in type « System.DateTime ».

Comment: what is the value in the `$xml.Event.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime`?

Comment: Here the content of test.xml < Property Name="TimeCreated" Type="System.DateTime">07/04/2020 15:07:14</Property>

Comment: This works for me:
`([Datetime]$xml.Property.'#text')`, can you share your whole code and xml?

Comment: Hello Shayky 
Code used is: 
Get-WinEvent -Path "Application.evt" -Oldest | ConvertTo-Xml -as Stream -Depth 10 > "C:\PSCode\test.xml"

[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path "C:\PSCode\test.xml"

Write-Host "Event: $($xml.Event.System.EventID.'#text')"

Write-Host "The $(([Datetime]$xml.Event.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")) on $($xml.Event.System.Computer), $($xml.Event.System.Provider.Name) raise the following message:`n$($xml.Event.EventData.Data)"

Regarding XML unfortunatelly I cannot share it, sensible data inside :(

Comment: Error is: 


Event: 
Unable to convert the value Null in type « System.DateTime ».
Character Ligne:8 : 19
+ Write-Host "The $([Datetime]$xml.Property.'#text') on $($xml.Event.Sy ...
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : nullToObjectInvalidCast
 
The  on ,  raise the following message:

Comment: Related line: 
<Property Name="TimeCreated" Type="System.DateTime">09/02/2021 20:07:54</Property>

Comment: Just remove the `[Datetime]`

Comment: No more error, thanks for that. unfortuantelly, message do not contains any information: Event: 
The  on ,  raise the following message:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.

I found a way to get informations needed

```
$events = Get-WinEvent  -FilterHashTable @{LogName = "Application"; id=302} -MaxEvents 50 | where {$_.Message -like '*'}
    foreach($event in $events){
    "-"*50                        
                write-host "Date:" $event.TimeCreated
                write-host "Source:"$event.ProviderName
                $event.Message             
    "-"*50
    }
```